# When is currying more efficient in deep neural nets?

Tags: complexity-theory, neural-networks

I'm reading a blog post on deep Q-learning, and it contrasts traditional lookup-table-based Q-learning with deep Q-learning:

> [image]

What I wonder about in this picture is: Why does the deep NN not also take a state and action as input? I assume that this has something to do with computational efficiency. Essentially, in the lower graph, the neural net is in "curried form".

**When is it more efficient for the deep NN to have type $S\times A \to \mathbb R$ (as the upper graph), and when is it more efficient to have type $S\to (A\to\mathbb R)$ (as the lower graph)?**